Do postgres use implicit transaction in UPDATE ... RETURNING queries?
Can someone let me know if Postgres 15 uses implicit transactions for UPDATE...RETURNING queries?
For example, is there any differences between the two queries
BEGIN;
UPDATE counter
SET value = value + 1
RETURNING value;
COMMIT;

and
UPDATE counter
SET value = value + 1
RETURNING value;

Table is like below
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS counter
(
    value      bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ        NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);


My understanding after reading compatibility note is that PostgreSQL does not support implicit transactions at all.

Why are you asking ? The basic modification operations (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) are atomic in most if not all database products. BTW PostgreSQL has a SEQUENCE that's a lot more efficient and scalable than a counter(s) tables.

What do you mean exactly when you say implicit transaction? Being be able to rollback the update without having to start a transaction manually, or ensuring the update is atomic and you get exactly the value that your update produced?

I am asking if the update is atomic and I get precisely the value that the update produced.

Yes, there can only be e difference when you Rollback and reselect, or reexecute the update and get the same value as before...

@PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I am aware of SEQUENCE, I just posted a simple schema for the question. INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE are atomic; I mainly asked about the RETURNING. The answer below & comments cleared my doubts.

From de documentation (Page 19), you can read:

PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed
within a transaction. If you do not issue a BEGIN command, then each
individual statement has an implicit BEGIN and (if successful) COMMIT
wrapped around it. A group of statements surrounded by BEGIN and
COMMIT is sometimes called a transaction block

This means that all transactions including UPDATE will be treated as transactions without having to explicitly specify them.

Not sure why they say this. If I'm not given the option to rollback a successful execution, can that be called a transaction? I have the impression that they're using the wrong wording to mean that statements are atomic. However, maybe the OP is making the same assumption.

Yes, I was also asking if statements are atomic and if I get precisely the value my update produced.

you have to read on. If you have a direct connection to Postgres, and send statements without begin and commit, every statement gets autocommited.
But if you use a tool, the tool decides whether to autocommit or not, and in a program mostly the framework etc...

Do not link to a~3000 page PDF when the documentation is available online and you can link to the page directly Transactions.

@ÁlvaroGonzález, no they are not. Read Start Transaction.
